# TextOptions.TextRenderingMode vs. Visual.VisualTextRenderingMode

Tags: wpf, text-rendering, cleartype

There appear to be two ways to set a [TextRenderingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textrenderingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration value on a **WPF** [Visual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is there any difference between using the [TextOptions.TextRenderingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textoptions.textrenderingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property (with or without its static getter/setters) versus the instance property [Visual.VisualTextRenderingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualtextrenderingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `Visual` base class?

I took a quick look in `Reflector`, but surprisingly it wasn't immediately clear that one method was calling the other or vice-versa. Each way seems to have a small, but non-trivial amount of proactively side-effecting code. I guess I was expecting those getter/setters to be more passive (i.e. simply recording state changes and then deferring to subsequent, centrally-coordinated action).

The enumeration itself lives in `System.Windows.Media`, so that doesn't come down on either side of the debate. In case you're curious, there are four modes available, as follows:

```
public enum TextRenderingMode
{
    Auto      /**/ = 0, // Text is rendered with the most appropriate rendering algorithm based on the layout mode that was used to format the text.
    Aliased   /**/ = 1, // Text is rendered with bilevel anti-aliasing.
    Grayscale /**/ = 2, // Text is rendered with grayscale anti-aliasing.
    ClearType /**/ = 3, // Text is rendered with the most appropriate ClearType rendering algorithm based on the layout mode that was used to format the text.
}
```

This isn't the only confusing rendering flag in **WPF**. Text and edge rendering (?) tweaks, and support for the various hinting and bitmap caching options seem to be amongst those rare areas of WPF where the API isn't organized (or comprehensively documented) very well.

Comment: Honestly seems to be the same exact thing, but what is the question here really?
If you dont like WPF options you can try UWP which has better calligraphy options.

Comment: @Mishka the question is about WPF. If you aren't interested in that topic, you can filter based on [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags).